# Additional characters appended while inserting Arabic words to MySQL using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to perform a simple insert in an Arabic web application based on plain JSP and servlets.

However, additional characters are getting inserted in addition to the Arabic words.

I am using `UTF8_unicode_ci collation` and the JSP pages are also configured to support UTF8. The connection string also includes UTF8 encoding parameter. Am I missing anything?

[image: Question marks added before text]